# Discrete mathematics power series

Tags: discrete-mathematics, power-series

I've hit a wall with this problem.

So, i have been given:

$A(x)=a0+a1*x+a2*x^2...ak*x^n$

and

$B(x)=1/(1-x)*A(x)$

How do i show that $[x^n]*B(x)=sum(ak, k=0 .. n)$.

I cant find a way through how to get rid of the x's.?

I have also tried rewriting the $1/1-x$, but it still doesnt help me.

Any ideas what i should do?

Thanks in advance. I hope someone can help :)

Comment: Please, clarify your notation. What does $[x^n]*B(x)$ mean?

Comment: @OP, use `\frac{x}{y}` to write $\frac{x}{y}$. Also, you use `\sum_{i=1}^{n} f(x)` to write $\sum_{i=1}^{n} f(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint : You should express the coefficients of $B$ using the Cauchy product of power series. Remark also that

$$\frac{1}{1-x}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^n$$